# Right click cancels hover state

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown menu with a `:hover` state, but it disappears whenever I right click inside the menu (to active the context menu). In other words, right clicking for the context menu cancels the `:hover` state, when it shouldn't. Is there any way to enable right click -> context menu inside a `:hover`ing div?

Comment: when you right click, your are not hovering on the element anymore.

Comment: What makes you think, that it shouldn't? I haven't looked at the specs, but generally that is what i have experienced and what I would expect. Usually the right-click-menu makes your mouse behave like it was outside of the browser.

Comment: Try using the [oncontextmenu event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oncontextmenu.asp) which you can use to assign a function when the element is right-clicked.  Then you can add a class to it that has the same styles as your :hover does.  You will need to UNdo this on the `mouseout` event.  Otherwise, you should assign the element [focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/#focus) to accomplish your goal.

Comment: SourceOverflow and Stenderit might very well be that its doing what its supposed to do, but that wasn't the problem here.

Thank you @mtr.web I will try that :)